# How are virtual nodes placed / calculated to implement consistent hashing

Tags: algorithms, hashing

I am reading about consistent hashing for system design and I understand the application of consistent hashing and the use of virtual nodes. I want to understand how to calculate the optimum number of virtual nodes and how to place them on the unit circle.

https://youtu.be/zaRkONvyGr8?t=433

in the above video the author explains that k hash functions are required, pass the key through each hash function to have k points for each server and the optimum number of hash functions k = log(M).

where M is number of servers (not sure if I completely understand this portion, feel free to correct me). The presenter in the video says "search space", but imo I think he means he means # of

How / Why does this work ?

Other resources I have gone through are:

- https://www.toptal.com/big-data/consistent-hashing
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing
- https://medium.com/@sandeep4.verma/consistent-hashing-8eea3fb4a598

but this portion isn't explained

Comment: I found something revelant.
You can check this out. https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbArch/archDataDistributeVnodesUsing.html